# EGit JGit not installing / Git not working in Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, plugins, vpn, egit

When installing egit - jgit plugin from [Latest EGit updates](https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/) site getting below error in eclipse

```
Unable to connect to repository https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-5.8/content.xml
Unable to connect to repository https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-5.8/content.xml
Connect to download.eclipse.org:443 [download.eclipse.org/198.41.30.199] failed: Connection refused: no further information
```

Comment: Your question and self answer at the same time looks a bit suspect. It makes no sense to recommend installing EGit, since Eclipse is shipped with EGit for years. Please also note, a Git repository and a p2 repository are two different things, and your answer (various troubleshooting for using it) doesn't really match your question (failing installing it).

Comment: @howlger my question is not answered in Stackoverflow. You marked duplicate answer is totally wrong to my solution. When I connect to VPN Network git synchronization or git updates not working. So I posted the answer with correct solution.

Comment: The error message mentioned in the question says that the update site is not accessible. If you're using VPN, you're in a different network, from which different websites, update sites and Git repositories may be accessible. In my case, I need to be connected via VPN (using Cisco AnyConnect) to be able to access certain Git repositories and update sites, which is the opposite of what you say. Apart from this basic thing, all that remains is `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` which in my view is a duplicate. I also do not understand why you ask a question for which you already know the answer.

Comment: @howlger `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` still not working in local PC when connected to VPN ( Cisco AnyConnect). My Client restricts git, Gmail, youtube, and other sites for their security. I searched in SOF and not found answer related to my problem that's why I posted the question and answered by self. Some companies may restirct git and other sites to access. Whenever I disconnected I am able to get GIT updates. Hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're connected to VPN or Cisco Connect **please try to disconnect from it**.

To Work on Eclipse Git Repository you need to disconnect from VPN Network **because client network restricts Git, Gmail and other sites to access from there network**.

If local PC / LP connected to office network you face Git synchronization issue `fetch operation failed git eclipse`, `push` and `pull` operational issues also you will face when VPN connected.